# Extract specific text from dataframe by separator count and position

Tags: python, regex, substring

Learning regular expressions and stumbled into a bit of a wall.
I have the following dataframe:

```
item_data=pandas.DataFrame({'item':['001','002','003'],
'description':['Fishing,Hooks,12-inch','Fishing,Lines','Fish Eggs']})
```

For each description, I want to be extract everything prior to the second comma ",". If there is no comma, then the original description is retained

Results should look like this:

```
item_data=pandas.DataFrame({'item':['001','002','003'],
'description':['Fishing,Hooks,12-inch','Fishing,Lines','Fish Eggs'],
'new_description':['Fishing,Hooks','Fishing,Lines', 'Fish Eggs']})
```

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a regexp...

```
re.sub("^([^,]*,[^,]*),.*$", "\\1", x)
```

meaning is

- `^` start of string
- `(` start capture
- `[^,]` anything but a comma
- `*` zero or more times
- `,` a comma
- `[^,]` anything but a comma
- `*` zero or more times
- `)` end of capture
- `,` another comma
- `.*` anything
- `$` end of string

Replacing with the content of group 1 (`\1`) drops whatever is present after the second comma

Comment: This is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
new_description = [",".join(i.split(",")[:2]) for i in item_data['description']]
```